# Domino 9 social edition setup wizard fail to launch

Tags: ibm-domino

I am installing domino 9 social Edition on a G7 HP Proliant Server running windows server 2003 R2. The setup wizard fail to launch after installing Java and configuring Java virtual machine.

Comment: More information is going to make it easier to get answers.  Things like exact error messages, log entries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Domino 9.0 Social Edition is not supported on Windows Server 2003. You need Windows Server 2008 or newer.
Check the documentation, section system requirements, for details.